# why can't i load 3d model in usina engine?

Tags: python, 3d

I have made a small 3D model and named it as `trial.glb`. I'm using the ursina engine and trying to insert the tree into the ursina window but I am not successful. when I try adding a cube which I saved I need to just load the texture but if I save the texture of my tree and try inserting it, I get a cube

Answer (score 2):

You should add the texture in entity brackets.

```
entity = Entity(model='model', texture='model's texture here', kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the same path as where is Your ".py" file:

```
model = Entity(model = 'trial.glb')
```

Also, if You put two of models as 'trial.glb' and cube they are added in the same coordinates, if you haven't set X,Y and Z axis yet for them. For Example, cube can be bigger in size than 'trial.glb' model, thats why you cant see both of them but only cube.
To see all models added one to another, you must enter Wireframe mode. Just found this code:

```
app.wireframe_on()
```

Then scroll with mouse wheel on the Ursina's window to get closer or farther to objects and rotate with right mouse button.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **** instead of **/** . \ for windows, and / for linux.